# CKEditor .Net Security Exception

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I have another issue with a Security Exception, although this feels like it should be easier to solve.

I've added in to my site the CKEditor .Net library (from here: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15882)

I've included it on my page as a normal control:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="FredCK.CKEditor" Namespace="FredCK.CKEditor" TagPrefix="ck" %>
```

and put it on the page:

```
<ck:CkEditor runat="server" id="Editor" Width="692px" Height="400px" />
```

However, when I run the page, I get this message:

```
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

In the CKEditor .Net project, there is a strongKey file...I imagine this is where I'm going wrong somewhere, but I just can't work out where.

Any ideas from anyone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to get it working by downloading a newer version of the dlls

Answer (score 1):

Is the file located on a UNC share? I've seen several articles where that caused this error.